# Changing Cors-Anywhere as a Node-Fetch

Tags: cors, cors-anywhere

I recently forked cors-anywhere (more precisely, a cors-anywhere fork, [cors-escape](https://github.com/shalvah/cors-escape)) and edited it, and it works exactly how I need it to! However, instead of running an http/https server that shows what I need, I want to make it into something like node-fetch (a module that requests the resource as cors-anywhere would like fetch). I know it has to do with these lines, but I am not sure what to do with them (and what to export as a module):

```js
    let server;
    if (options.httpsOptions) {
        server = require('https').createServer(options.httpsOptions, requestHandler);
    } else {
        server = require('http').createServer(requestHandler);
    }
```

How could I modify them to make and return a request instead? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are after? It's hard to understand the way it's written right now.

Comment: @Evert I think I added an edit that shows what he/she needs, but I honestly don't know either.